# effectiveGasPrice doesn't exist on BSC network

Tags: ethers.js, bsc

I'm trying to calculate in ethers.js the cost of a transaction on BSC.
I found on another thread the following snippet of code:

```
getTxCost = async (txHash) => {
        let receipt = await provider.getTransactionReceipt(txHash);
        return receipt.effectiveGasPrice.mul(receipt.gasUsed);
 };
```

but the problem is that effectiveGasPrice seems to not exist on BSC.
How can I get this value?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

face the same issue today. Not the best solution, but i get the value via https://docs.ethers.io/v5/api/providers/provider/#Provider-getGasPrice

```
gasPrice = await provider.getGasPrice()
```

From bscscan, the value seems to be quite constant, 5 Gwei. But still, this is just a best guess of gasPrice. Hopefully there will be a better solution soon.